# Prestashop 1.6.1.16 - My js file is loaded, but my functions aren't seen

Tags: javascript, php, html, overriding, prestashop

I am new in Prestashop (1.6.1.16).
I work in default prestashop theme (default-bootstrap).

What I did:

I put content in `/themes/default-bootstrap/product.tpl`:
right after top comments (those about LICENSE and others):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/ask_bid/js/ask.js">
    </script>
    <button onclick="take_asks({$product->id})">See asks</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="product-id" value="{$product->id}" />
    <input type="hidden" id="customer-id" value="{$id_customer}" />

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-
                    dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

         </div>
    </div>
```

Where `{$product->id}` comes from

```
/controllers/front/ProductController.php<br>
```

and `{$id_customer}` comes from

```
/override/controllers/front/ProductController.php
```

I created `/modules/ask_bid/js/ask.js` where I put next content:

```
function isJSON(data) {
    var ret = true;
    try {
        JSON.parse(data);
    }catch(e) {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}


function take_asks (id_product) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseDir + 'modules/ask_bid/ajax.php',
        data: 'method=take_asks&id_product='+id_product,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(json) {
            if(isJSON(json)) {
                var json = JSON.parse(json);
                //alert("json: " + json[0].comment);

            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Also the modal doesn't act like one
My modal is displayed (not hidden) and that is not normal.
It is right after button instead being "in the air" (I hope you know what I mean).

And I have js error:

The `/modules/ask_bid/js/ask.js` is loaded (I see this also in INSPECT->f12/Network), but the `take_asks()` is not seen.

I get next console error (when I press 'Take asks' button):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: take_asks is not defined
>           at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.php?
>       id_product=6&controller=product&id_lang=1:413)

What I tried

-I deleted class_index.php
-I deleted cache (with CTRL-f5)
-I tried to add js file from /override/controllers/front/ProductController.php

but doesn't work and i also don't get errors:

```
public function setMedia()
{
    $this->addJS('modules/ask_bid/js/ask.js');

    parent::setMedia();
}
```

...or...

```
function init () {
    $this->context->controller->addJS('modules/ask_bid/js/ask.js');

    parent::init()
}
```

What do you think I can do?

Comment: @il_raffa! Wouldn't necessary to edit my Ask. I customized it well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a hookheader in your module:

```
public function hookHeader($params)
{
    $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'js/ask.js');
}
```

You can add it only on product pages with:

```
public function hookHeader($params)
{
    if (!isset($this->context->controller->php_self) || $this->context->controller->php_self != 'product')
           return;
    $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'js/ask.js');
}
```

and in your module install hook to header with

```
$this->registerHook('header'))
```

To add content to the product page without changing the themes tpls (as mentioned in comments) you can use the displayFooterProduct that "Add new blocks under the product description.".

```
public function hookDisplayFooterProduct($params)
{
    return "code you want to insert";
}
```

Inside this hook you can access the following parameters:
$params = array('product' => Product, 'category' => Category)

Also, remember to hook it on install with `$this->registerHook('displayFooterProduct'))` and if the module is already installed, reset it or manually hook it.

Comment: The point is, i don't how to put my modal exactly where I want. That's why my modal doesn't act like one. It is just a folder. I modify in particular .tpls from theme.

Comment: If you have any idea of how to add my modal in what page I want and exxactly where I want, you are my guest. I know how to create a modal and "install" it or to "hook" it (left, up, right, etc...). But I don't know to add it exactly where I want into an element from .tpl theme. I hope you get what I mean,

Comment: More exactly, I would like to can create an modal (which will have .tpls, controllers and stuff), but I don't think it'll can go inside a theme page without modifing .tpls theme...

Comment: so you want to add content (the modal code) to the product page? Only the product page? Without changing the theme tpl?

Comment: Yeah. Is that possible? Should I use my module controllers or /controllers/front/ProductController,php?

Comment: I've edited my answer with one way to add code to the product page without changing or overriding the template tpl.

Comment: Ok. It is not as I hoped. So let's say I want modify theme too. The theme see all modules which are installed?

Comment: It is so hard for my to understand. It isn't a private chat where you can explain me with  details?

Comment: If you want to override the module theme, you can use another hook to set a different tpl with `Hook::exec('DisplayOverrideTemplate', array('controller' => $this));` depending on the controller set the tpl or return false if you don't want to change the tpl.

Comment: I am sorry. I can't "accept your answer". I still don't understand how pages works with modules, or how a module works with another module, or how theme works with modules. Maybe you know some usefull links.